# Value representation of non-trivially copyable types

Tags: c++, object, memory-model

I'm intrigued by the following paragraph from the standard (§3.9/4 of *ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)*):

> The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of *N* `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where *N* equals `sizeof(T)`. The *value representation* of an object is the set of bits that hold the value of type `T`. For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a *value*, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.<sup>42</sup>

I understand that the *object representation* and *value representation* are distinct to allow some of the object representation to not take part in the value of the object (for example, padding). I don't quite get the point about trivially copyable types though. Do non-trivially copyable types not have values? Can part of the value representation of a non-trivially copyable type exist outside its object representation?

Note 42 explains:

> The intent is that the memory model of C++ is compatible with that of ISO/IEC 9899 Programming Language C.

I still don't understand why the previous statement is specifically for trivially copyable types only though. What is the significance of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard example is a class that manages a resource:

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar * p;

    Foo() : p(new Bar) { }
    ~Foo() { delete p; }

    // copy, assign
};
```

An object of type `Foo` has a value, but that value is not copyable by copying the object representation (which is just the value of `p` in this case). Copying an object of type `Foo` requires copying the *se­man­tics* of the class, which say "an object *owns* the pointee". A suitable copy thus requires an appropriate, user-defined copy constructor:

```
Foo::Foo(Foo const & rhs) : p(new Bar(*rhs.p)) { }
```

Now the object representation of an object of type `Foo` is different from the object representation of a copy of such an object, although they have the same value.

By contrast, the value of an `int` is the same as that of another `int` as soon as the object representations coincide. (This is a sufficient, though not necessary, condition, due to padding.)

Comment: I don't understand when you say "..., although they have the same value." when the value of `p` in one object is different from the one copied from the first object.