# Is there a significant difference between value representation of trivially-copyable and perhaps not

Tags: c++, object, types

I've come across the definition of the value/object representation of type **T**. 3.8/4 gives one to us:

> The object representation of an object **of type T** is the sequence of N
>   unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals
>   sizeof(T). The value representation of an object is the set of bits
>   that hold the value of type T. **For trivially copyable types**, the value
>   representation is a set of bits in the object representation that
>   determines a value, which is one discrete element of an
>   implementation-defined set of values.

I can't imagine the difference of these definitions for a trivially compyable types between for any other types. What excatly restriction applies to a trivially copyable type?
I would like to look at an example, if any, of such distinction.

Comment: Not sure if enough for an answer but if an object isn't a trivially copyable one it might have to do some resources cleanup (and in very low-level contexts that isn't just plain simple and might rely on fixed addresses).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value representation of non-trivially copyable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773640/value-representation-of-non-trivially-copyable-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object isn't a trivially copyable one it might have to do some resources initialization/cleanup (and in very low-level contexts that isn't just plain simple and might rely on fixed addresses).

Having two different objects which *think* they both have acquired an hardware resource is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Is the _value_ an abstraction of the standard? I mean, the value is a property of an object according to c++ object model described in 1.8. Right?

Comment: I believe you can only specify that as in §3.9.4 if the object is a trivially copyable one. With non-trivially copyable ones the set space can't be enforced: it's implementation-defined (and might be extremely large as well)

Comment: It seems I'm beginning to understand. That's an object of not trivially copyable type has no value or it has no value to copy?I thing the latter is true, because of _The value representation of an object is the set of bits that hold the **value of type T.**_

Comment: Exactly, that passage only holds for trivially copyable objects